# Do you get skill points with each legend level?

Tags: dying-light

Should each legend level give 1 legendary skill point? I'm on 3rd legend level and I have only 2 legendary points. Is this normal, or did some bug make me miss one point?

Answer (score 2):

Your character starts off a Legend Level 1 with no points earned. Because of this the number of points you have cumulatively earned will lag by 1 point compared to your Legend Level.

Here's a brief chart to explain this:

```
Legend Level | Points Earned | Cumulative Points Earned
     1       |        0      |            0
     2       |       +1      |            1
     3       |       +1      |            2
     4       |       +1      |            3
```

and so on...

You will earn an experience point for every legend level you unlock, but the fact they don't align is not a bug.